# Determing density function from CDF

Tags: probability

I know that if I've got a CDF for a random variable, and if it's concentrated and continuously differentiable on an interval $(a,b)$, then the distribution is continuous and it has a density function given by it's derivative, but how does one calculate this derivative, or even decide if the CDF meets the conditions, when it is a piecewise function, which it often is?

For example, here's one from my textbook: 
$$\begin{cases} 
0          & \text{when } \le 0       \\ 
x/3        & \text{when } 0 < x \le 1 \\ 
2x/3 - 1/3 & \text{when } 1 < x \le 2 \\
1          & \text{when } x > 2
\end{cases}$$

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do when the CDFs are like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can still compute the derivative of a piecewise differentiable function away from the points where the definition changes. The derivative need not be defined at those points, but one can just replace the values at those points in the derivative with arbitrary values without affecting the probability distribution. Probability density functions need not be continuous and the distribution is not affected by changes on a set of measure 0.